# Unmappable character for encoding while installing web3j

Tags: java, gradle, encoding, build, ethereum

I've download the Etherium Client Java Library **web3j** from git repository. When I try to compile the sources it fails because some of the source files are created with UTF-8 encoding but gradle take my operating system default encoding (Cp1250).

```
C:\web3j\web3j-master>gradlew install

> Task :crypto:javadoc FAILED
C:\web3j\web3j-master\crypto\src\main\java\org\web3j\crypto\Sign.java:102: error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1250
    //        routine specified in Section 2.3.7, where mlen = Ôî?(log2 p)/8Ôîë or mlen = Ôî?m/8Ôîë.
                                                                 ^
C:\web3j\web3j-master\crypto\src\main\java\org\web3j\crypto\Sign.java:102: error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1250
    //        routine specified in Section 2.3.7, where mlen = Ôî?(log2 p)/8Ôîë or mlen = Ôî?m/8Ôîë.

^
2 errors
```

How to force gradle to take UTF-8 encoding instead of operating system default encoding?

Answer (score 0):

```
apply plugin: "java"
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
  options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
```

Comment: Proposed solution does not help in my case but thanks anyway. I've already found a  workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the UTF-8 chars from erroneous Java sources (there were only few of them and they were all part of the Java comments). After modification gradle build was successful.